# Form template with controls as TabPage

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, tabpage

I have a tabpage which displays a summary of records in my database, when the user clicks a row a new tabpage opens, this uses a form as a 'template' which has textboxes, the textboxes will display the detailed data from the specific row.

The stumbling point I am at is I can get to the point where the new tabpage opens with the form template displayed but I dont know how to fill the textboxes on the new tabpage / form with the data from the database (based on the row the user selected). How do I reference the textboxes on the new tabpage and assign them the appropriate fields? Do I bind the 'templates' textboxes and then fill them with a query?

I have tried this...

```
Me.tabMain.TabPages(NewTab).Controls(frmRecipeDisplay.Controls(txtVersion).Text = "test")
```

But this causes an error.

This app is in VB.NET.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint, after creating the form and tab. Try doing a value peek (mouse hover over the var for the new form, click + ). For the new form.controls array, you should be able to reach the fields on that form.

Comment: I tried this... Me.tabMain.TabPages(NewTab).Controls(frmRecipeDisplay.Controls(txtVersion).Text = "test") but I still get an error, I looked through the breakpoint like you advised. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @GordonHepburn You could add a tag containing the record ID to each record displayed, and when the user clicks it, pass the ID to the new tab.  From there you can query the database with that ID and populate the textboxes from there. However, you are not showing us any code, if you show some code we would be able to help much better.

Comment: @GordonHepburn Also, please don't post code in the comments, rather edit your question to include the code in a `code block`

Comment: @TheWhiteWolf the name of the new tab is a concatenation of 2 fields from the selected row which identify the unique record in the database. The issue I have is that I have no idea how to reference the textboxes on the new tab page, even if I just want to write "test" to them I dont know how.

Comment: The closest thing to a "template" in WinForms would be to create a UserControl, create a new instance of it, and add it to the new TabPage.

Comment: @LarsTech Instead I have a form, I create an instance of that and add that to the new TabPage, are there any issues with this approach? If so can you detail them please. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You can turn a form into a UserControl by setting TopLevel = false, and give it no border.

Comment: @LarsTech, if so then how do I reference the textboxes on the new form / usercontrol... that is the original question... I have no problem using a form in this way, my problem is i dont know how to reference the controls it contains... i dont know how to be any clearer.

Comment: Lots of different ways to do that.  You can create properties on the form that access the controls.  A simple cheat is to change the modifier property on the control to make it public, then you can directly access it. `Dim f As New Form1()  f.TextBox1.Text = "data"`